# Crawl Errors "SharePoint returned an empty response"

Tags: search-results, crawling, crawl, crawled-property

I have some problems with crawling of content. The crawl logs show that 99% of errors are caused by .pdf files.

Most of the errors look like:

> FullUrl: https://myServer/*.PDF
>
> ErrorId: 806
>
> IsDeleted False
>
> LogLevel 0
>
> ErrorLevel: 2
>
> StatusMessage: "SharePoint returned an empty response. ( SearchID =
>   XYZ... )"

Comment: What version of SP? Are the PDF files valid? Are they HUGE? are they password protected or in some other way blocked to the Crawl Account user? (Test by accessing the site and the documents as the Crawl Account.)